# 0 Android device supported, after uploading the new build

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I know this question has been asked multiple times, and I have tried all the accepted answers
 but no success. I am working on a flutter app and build created on new Flutter 1.7.
Here is the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ifinca"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.PHOTO_LIBRARY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
android:resizeableActivity="false"
android:label="iFinca"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
<!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
<meta-data
android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
android:value="true" />

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" >
</supports-screens>
</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

sourceSets {
main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
// TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
applicationId "com.tsts"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28
multiDexEnabled true
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

}

buildTypes {
release {

signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}
}
}

flutter {
source '../..'
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
// implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Posted the Gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed this feature from the `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.PHOTO_LIBRARY" />
```

That's why play-store is showing 0 devices supported because no android device supports this.